# list内包表記で単一の文字列から複数の文字列を取り除く方法はあるでしょうか

Tags: python

私の質問の概要は、リスト内包表記で文字列から複数の不要な文字列を除去する処理の書き方です。

例えば、

```
"a皆a様aよbろbしbくcおc願cいcしNULLまNULLす。"
```

から不要な["a","b","c","NULL"]を除去して

```
"皆様よろしくお願いします。"
```

を得るために

```
words = "a皆a様aよbろbしbくcおc願cいしNULLまNULLす。"
alist = ["a", "b", "c","NULL"]
for delstr in alist:
    words = words.replace(delstr, "")
```

という処理をしています。しかし、wordsは多数存在し、alistも巨大なため、リスト内包表記で高速化が出来ないかと考え、以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
[words.replace(delstr, "") for delstr in alist]
```

しかし、これではwordsからalistのそれぞれの要素を除去したリストが得られてしまうため、目的を果たせません。

一つの方法は上記のwordsをリスト内包表記にしてalistの要素をループ毎にwordsのリストから除去する方法ですが、もし内包表記で単一のオブジェクトに複数の処理ことができるならばwordsのリストとalistを一括して内包表記にできるため、より望ましいと考えています。wordsからalistの要素すべてをリスト内包表記で除去する方法があればご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: > wordsは多数存在し、alistも巨大 [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)な気がします。必要なのは、wordsからalistの内容を除去する処理であり、リスト内包処理は別に必要ないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: alist は １ 文字のリストではなく、ワード(1 文字以上の文字列)のリストという事でしょうか？

Comment: その通りで、alistにはワード"NULL"等も含まれています。

Comment: さて、削除したいものが「文字」から「文字列」になったことで、この問題はぐっと難しくなっています。 PicoSushi さんがおっしゃっているように、「内包表記で」といった制約ははずされたほうがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: 文字列と文字の処理は異なると言うことを理解しました。str.maketransの手法はwordsから”NULL"も除去できているのでうまく動いているように見えます。しかし、maketrans関数を経ると空白が削除される場合があるようで、例えば"ＴＯＫＹＯ　ＭＸ　ＮＥＷＳ　"が"ＴＯＫＹＯＭＸＮＥＷＳ"になり、その後のmecabの処理では結果が異なってくるようです。alistのループをforのままにした場合とmaketrans関数を利用した場合では後者が1割程度高速で、もともと除去する予定の文字列には空白も含まれていたのでmaketrans関数を理解して、こちらを使う方法で実装してみたいと思います。

Comment: なるほど、wordsには殆どが全角で入っているので一見うまく動いているようでしたが、それだと問題がありますね。

Comment: 例えば words に `IS_NULL` という単語が含まれている場合、単純置換では `IS_` が残りますが、それは構いませんか？

Comment: re.sub や functools.reduce を使うと本当に高速化するのか、テスト結果でわかれば教えてください。

Answer (score 5):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/re.html#re.sub) を使う案です。

```
import re
words_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(w) for w in alist))
result = re.sub(words_re, '', words)
```

削除文字列（`alist`）の内容によっては `replace` を繰り返した場合とは違う結果になるので注意して下さい。例えば、

```
words = "<abc>"
alist = ["b", "abc"]
```

だとすると、`replace` では `b` の削除のみが起こり結果は `<ac>`で、正規表現だと先に `abc` のマッチが始まるので `abc` が削除され結果は `<>` になります。

Comment: ジェネレーターの内包表記というのを知りました。早速実コードに埋め込んでみましたが、除去したいwordのlistには"null", "UNK(....)"等が含まれているので少し改善をしてみたいと思います。

Comment: str.maketransを使う方法、うまく動いているように見えます。しかし、もとのforループをかけたものと、ご教示頂いた手法で得られたwordsの結果が厳密に一致していないケースがあり、原因を模索しているところです。

Comment: 「文字列」と「文字」についてのご指摘ありがとうございます。編集します。

Comment: 古い回答に対するコメントは削除しました（このコメントも後ほど削除します）。

Answer (score 3):

高階関数の`functools.reduce`を使うと1行で書くことができます。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/functional.html#the-functools-module

```
def func(a, b):
  return a.replace(b, "")

words = "a皆a様aよbろbしbくcおc願cいしNULLまNULLす。"
alist = ["a", "b", "c","NULL"]
functools.reduce(func, alist, words)
```

これをラムダ式を使って書くと

```
functools.reduce(lambda a, b:a.replace(b, ""), alist, words)
```

ただし、ドキュメントには、「多くの場合 functools.reduce() を使うよりは、単に for ループを書いたほうがわかりやすくなります」とあります。